# Corona Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, coronasdk

I had implemented `Facebook Single Sign On` in my app. Then I discovered it did not work if the user already had the fb app installed on their phone. I resolved this by generating a key hash for facebook, everything worked again. Since then I upgraded my Corona account from trial to the pro version. Now my facebook is not working again. I am still using the `Android Debug key` when building the apk file, and I have tried the original `Hash Key` which I had and made another one, but I can't get it to work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the reason unknown to me, my Facebook Hash Key changed. I ran "adb logcat" when using my app on the device. In the logcat Facebook will tell you what Hash Key was expected. Copy/paste this into your Facebook Developer page and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, we had the same. 
Steps : Make a tutorial facebook login example with corona.
Try, thats will work with installed facebook app.
After implement facebook login into your app like in example.

That was the resolution for us.

But i cant say nothing exact, i got that app by another developer for some update/bugfixes.

Comment: I have been through all this, I had my Facebook Login for my app working with the Facebook app. Since I got a pro Corona account it does not work. I deleted the Facebook app to see if Single Sign On was still working and it is.